# PhoneGap ios application Map can't show

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

I have tried many methods to show the mapView in phonegap application that online provided. but still cant works. here is my code. Hope someone can help me to solve the problem
Thanks in advance

this is the map.js file code

```
function onMapLoad(){
        if(isConnected){
            //load google api
            var fileref=document.createElement('script');
            fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
            fileref.setAttribute("src","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&callback="+"getGeolocation");
            document.getElementByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
        }
        else{
            alert("Must be connected to the internet");
        }
    }



 function getGeolocation(){
    var options ={
    maximumAge:3000,
    timeout:5000,
    enableHighAccuracy:true
    };
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(loadMap,geoError,options);
   }

  function loadMap(position){
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
                                    position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
var myOptions ={
zoom:8;
center:latlng,
myTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var mayObj = document.getElementById("map_canvas");
var map = new google.maps.Map(mapObj,myOptions);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                    position:latlng,
                                    map:map,
                                    title:"You"

                                    });
 }
  function geoError(error){
alert('code: '+error.code +'\n' +'message: '+error.message +'\n');
 }
  $(document).bind("pageload",onMapLoad);
```

Here is the map.html file

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Map page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,    minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js"></script>

       </head>
<body>
    <div data-role ="page" id="map-page">
    <div id ="map_canvas" style =" width:300px; height:400px">
    </div>
         <script type="text/javascript" charset ="utf-8" src="js/map.js"></script>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```